# try except in Vyper language

Tags: vyper

I want to call a function on an external contract from a Vyper contract.

I want to handle a potential revert of this call.

Python try...except is not implemented in Vyper. What should i do instead ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the return value from the external call in this case? And if it isn't what you expected, either `assert()` or `raise`?

Comment: external calls reverts if they fail

Comment: I have this question too.  If for no other reason, than to help with testing and debugging.